# SharePoint Analytics to get page visit count

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, web-analytics

Can anyone provide a way to get individual site page's visit count using SharePoint analytics for one year, month wise?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a page view report in SharePoint site.

Go to site settings->site collection administration->audit log report-> Content viewing.
It will generate the view count for the page in the report.

And you also could get the view count of one page by custom code. For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Step by steps on how to display Most Visited Sites with number of view count in SharePoint 2013 Web Analytics.](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-steps-on-how-to-display-Most-Visited-Sites-with-number-of-view-count-in-SharePoint-2013-Web-Analytics)

[SharePoint 2013: Showing Page Views within a SharePoint Page.](http://spdeveloper.co.in/sharepoint2013/page-views-hit-counter-on-a-sharepoint-page.aspx)